# Windows 10 desktop icons are disordered when an external display is attached

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, icons

I am using a laptop and sometimes I plug in an external (and bigger) monitor via a docking station. The problem is that I have my desktop icons arranged in my laptop (picture 1) but when I attach it to the docking station I see them in the wrong order in the bigger display (picture 2).

I think it may have something to do with different resolutions and/or scale (my laptop has 125% scale while the bigger screen is set to 100%). But I need them that way so that applications are displayed properly in both screens.

When I unplug the bigger screen the icons get back to the right position but only if I don't change them. If I try to rearrange them, they become completely disordered when disconnecting the external display.

Why is happening this to me and how can I get the icons to respect their position even if I change the display resolution/scale?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: The terminology you're using is incorrect. Resolution and scaling are different things. When you mention 125% and 100% that's the scale, not the resolution.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thank you for the nuance, I changed it in my question.

Comment: I organize icons into the top left (room at bottom and right). Then I can display at different resolution (say projector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option is to use the Desktop icons layout save utilities. Save the location before any manipulation or configure the automation in the utility and restore after.
A good option is https://softwareok.com/?Download=DesktopOK

Comment: I don't know how, but installing that program fixed the problem: now I don't have to save the desktop and restore it. Just works all of a sudden. Probably has something to do with the instalation of that software but I am not sure.

Comment: After some time, now I need to restore the icons with DesktopOK each time but the program has become a must in my laptop everyday use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

1. On your desktop => right click and choose "Personalize"
2. Choose "Themes";
3. "Desktop icons" - on your right under "Related settings"
4. uncheck "Allow themes to change desktop icons"

It worked for me.

Good luck,
A3[Unchek the box "Allow themes to change desktop icons"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uaWq.png)